# Unable to sign file using openssl_pkcs7_sign on MacOS X 10.11.16

Tags: macos, lamp, php-openssl

I need to sign a file that I create(For the purpose of our discussion - lets call it unsignedfile.xml). This file is written to the folder where my php page is (unsignedfile.xml will be alongside index.php).

I'm on php 5.5.38. I have a .cer file issue to me (Class 2 signing certificate).

I attempted the following

```
$clearfile = "unsignedfile.xml";
$encfile = $clearfile . ".enc";

openssl_pkcs7_sign(realpath($clearfile), realpath($encfile),
    'file://'.realpath('/path/to/my/file/issued.cer'),
    array ('file://'.realpath('/path/to/my/file/issued.cer'), "99999999"),
    array ()
    );
```

However i have been getting an error

```
Warning: openssl_pkcs7_sign(): error getting private key in /path/to/my/php/site/index.php on line xyz
```

Any assistance would be very much appreciated.

Possible suspects in my mind..
 1. Do I need to import this .cer file to mac osx keychain? .. I did but still the same result OR SHOULD the import should be in a different format?
2. Am I missing any todo's in my apache server?

Comment: You need the private key that matches the public key in the certificate. This is not part of the certificate itself, although it's sometimes stored along with the cert in a PKCS#12 (.p12) file. It should've been created before or at the same time as the certificate. Where and how was this certificate created?

Comment: Where and how this certificate created?.. I bought from a licensed issuer of digital certificates an was told it has both public and private keys for signing (It came in a pen drive). So i exported it from a windows machine with an extension .cer (well that was the only option available).. So should I convert that .cer file to a .p12 file ?

Comment: The usual way to get signed certs is for you to create a private key and certificate signing request (CSR) file, submit the CSR to a signing authority, and then they send back a cert derived from the CSR. Did you do something like this? If so, the key should've been produced along with the CSR.

Comment: To clarify: the private key is not part of the certificate proper (although people sometimes refer to the private key + cert pair as just "a certificate"). It cannot be derived from the certificate, no matter where you import/export/whatever it, nor can it be recreated. If it's not available from wherever it was created, the cert will be useless.